# Bootstrap 4 table column width not formatting correctly in IE11 and Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, html-table

Has anyone encountered an issue with Bootstrap 4 table columns not being formatted correctly when using IE11 or Microsoft Edge?

Please check out the fiddle --
https://jsfiddle.net/vqazpa15/

(This doesn't work  in IE11 / Edge but works in Firefox/Chrome)

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="row">
            <th class="col-2">column 1</th>
            <th class="col-3">column 2</th>
            <th class="col-7">column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

(This works in all browsers that I tested)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">column 1</div>
    <div class="col-3">column 2</div>
    <div class="col-7">column 3</div>
</div>
```

There are two examples in the fiddle.  The first example the content is wrapped in a table.  The second the content wrapped in a div.  As you can see both examples format just fine in Firefox and Chrome but in IE11 and Edge only the 'div' example formats properly -- the table gets all screwy.

Does anyone know what's going on??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can confirm this, still applies to `v4.0.0-beta1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created an [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23493#issuecomment-322812030) on [Bootstrap's Github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) and [Mark](https://github.com/mdo) said not to use the `row` and `col` classes on tables, because they are flexboxes and thus break the display properties of tables.